# Can I inrease google calendar api usage limits to create huge amount of calendars by one service account

Tags: google-calendar-api

My app manage some events and use calendar api (authorize as service account). 
It creates google calendar for every user and shares this calendar with him in read only mode.
But It can create onle 25 calendars in a short period according to https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en

So I would like to increase google calendar api usage limits to create more than 25 calendars.
Can I do it using billable account?

Comment: Which type of account do you have?

Comment: I have free service acount.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the  link you posted you can do it with a billable account. You will then be able to create up to 60 calendars

[image]

Please take into consideration that:

> *This number is true, only if a user’s limits are fully replenished. If a user does any actions in this table regularly, then the actual use limit may differ.

Also, you can request more quota if needed. Please see: [Monitor API quotas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355?hl=en)

[image]